# Get the field value from a div id in a php form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm working in basketball lineup feature, where I have the 5 starters plus 3 reserves. I can drag and drop the players around, but I would like to store in a mysql database the 5 starters.

I have the basketball court with the 5 starters coming from the database and another 3 guys in the bench. I developed a system where I can move the players around swapping them as I like but I'm struggling to store the new composition in the database. I just need to store the 5 starters identified by their ids.

I tried using jquery to give the id of the player to a hidden field but I cannot make it work.

This is how I present the players in the court (this is the example of one of them, the rest are the same):

```
<form name="test" method="post" action="saveLineup.php">
    <div id="pos1" class="lineup1">
        <?php       

                $query = "SELECT *
                          FROM squad
                          WHERE user = '".$user."'";

                $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
                $file = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

                $starters = unserialize($file["starters"]);

                $sql1 = "SELECT *
                         FROM players
                         WHERE id = '".$starters[0]."'";

                $res1 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql1);      
                $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array( $res1 );

        ?>                              
        <div class="dragdiv" id="show1" onclick="popup(1)" style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block;" data-value="<?php echo $row1["id"];?>">                  
           <img src="images/players/<?php echo $row1["name"]; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $row1["name"]; ?>" title="<?php echo $row1["name"]; ?>" width="70" height="70">
           <input type="hidden" id="player" name="player1" value="" />
    </div>
```

I tried using this fiddle that I found in here: http://jsfiddle.net/bk8bgqo9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dragdiv = $('.dragdiv');
    var inputD = $('#player');
    dragdiv.on('click', function() {
    var valueD = $(this).data('value');
    inputD.val(valueD);
    console.log(valueD);

        });
});
```

In the fiddle I can see how when I click on any number, the field is populated with that value. This behaviour is exactly what I need in my code to do but instead of clicking in a div, populate the field value as soon as I drag and drop the new player. This drag and drop feature is working like a charm but I'm stuck in storing the data in the database :(

Is that possible?

Thanks so much in advance and sorry for my English and low knowledge of jquery/javascript.

Comment: Where is inputF declared?

Comment: Hi @Gopi, thanks for the correction. I just modified the code. It was a copy&paste mistake from the fiddle! :S

Comment: Still don't see inputF variable. Check again

Comment: Why do you need inputF variable??

Comment: Seems there is lag when you mentioned you modified code and from my end it was still showing usage of inputF without declaration, that's why I was asking it is still missing... now it looks good.

Comment: Ahhhh, cool :). In the example they use 2 variables, one for the field shown and one for hidden, but I just need this last one, that's why I removed it.

Comment: $(this).data('value') -- this won't work as your Div does not have a attribute data-value. See how the Div is defined in fiddle and compare with yours

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Hi @Gopi, ouch! Thanks a lot for the correction. I changed the original code to correct what you pointed out. Although I made the changes, I still can't make it work. Nothing has changed. The hidden input does NOT take any value :(. I believe the mistake can be in this line: dragdiv.on('click', function(). As I'm not clicking but dragging and dropping...any more ideas? Thanks a lot in advance!